# The inner product on $\mathfrak{h}^*$ induced by the inner product on $\mathfrak{h}$.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics, quantum-groups

I am reading [the book](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Guide_to_Quantum_Groups.html?id=bn5GNkLfnsAC). On page 80, there is a concept the inner product on $\mathfrak{h}^*$ induced by the inner product on $\mathfrak{h}$. Here $\mathfrak{h}$ is a Cartan subalgebra of a Lie algebra $g$. My questions are:

(1) how the inner product on $\mathfrak{h}$ is defined?

(2) how to define the inner product on $\mathfrak{h}^*$ using the inner product on $\mathfrak{h}$?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathfrak{g}$ is always a semisimple Lie algebra in this context. This means that it has a nondegenerate [Killing form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form). The inner product on $\mathfrak{h}$ is the restriction of the Killing form to $\mathfrak{h}$; it remains nondegenerate.

If $V$ is any vector space equipped with a nondegenerate bilinear form $B(-, -)$, then $B$ defines an isomorphism $V \cong V^{\ast}$, and you can define a bilinear form on $V^{\ast}$ using this isomorphism. There are a couple of ways to do this, but if $B$ is symmetric they all agree.